# In Android application's by using "android play core library" not getting "In App Review" pop up

Tags: android, kotlin

Hope Android folks get to know recently google provided "In App-Review" feature.

I wrote in java and used below version of the core-library.

**implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0'**

And my play store application one of the screen "OnCreate()" method wrote below piece of code. By enabling debug point check all code is executing but not getting "In APP-Review" popup. Can anyone help on this, Thanks !!

```
    ReviewManager manager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(this);
    Task<ReviewInfo> request = manager.requestReviewFlow();
    request.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<ReviewInfo>() {
      @Override
      public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<ReviewInfo> task) {
         if (task.isSuccessful()) {
           // We can get the ReviewInfo object
           ReviewInfo reviewInfo = task.getResult();
           Task<Void> flow = manager.launchReviewFlow(SelectShippingActivity.this, reviewInfo);
/*           flow.addOnCompleteListener(task2 -> {
             // The flow has finished. The API does not indicate whether the user
             // reviewed or not, or even whether the review dialog was shown. Thus, no
             // matter the result, we continue our app flow.
           });*/
          flow.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task1) {
              //For testing added println statement.
              System.out.println(task1);
              // The flow has finished. The API does not indicate whether the user
              // reviewed or not, or even whether the review dialog was shown. Thus, no
              // matter the result, we continue our app flow.
            }
          });
         }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar google bug raised by some of the people

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/162969017